Suppose that $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$ for all $a$
Since $f$ is continuous at $0$...$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0(\forall x\in \mathbb{R})[|x-0|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x)-0|]<\epsilon$$
It is quite easy to see that $f(0)=0$ which implies $f(a-a)=f(a)+f(-a)=0$.  This implies $f(x-a)=f(x)-f(a)$. If we make the substitution $x-a$ for $x$ we have $$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0(\forall x\in \mathbb{R})[|(x-a)-0|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x-a)-0|]<\epsilon$$ which implies
$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0(\forall x\in \mathbb{R})[|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|]<\epsilon$$
Q.E.D
I would like to know if the $x-a$ substitution is valid, and if I have the right idea. Thanks!

Don't mix formal and informal language. Here, "s.t." Is informal, and completely  unnecessary because $\exists \delta P(\delta)$ means "There exists a $\delta$ such that $P(\delta).$"

If $x_n\to a$ then $x_n-a\to 0.$ Thus $f(x_n)-f(a)=f(x_n-a)\to f(0)=0.$

I think you have the right idea but you are expressing it poorly. First prove $f(0)=0$ [I wouldn't use any $f(a-a)$ as we can't distribute over negatives yet... I'd use $f(0) = f(0+0) = f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)$]. Then prove $f(-x)=-f(x)$ [as $f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$]  Then as $f$ is continuous at $0$ that for all $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ where $|x-0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)|< \epsilon$ but that implies if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|(x-a)-0<\delta$ so $|f(x-a)-f(0)|=|f(x-a)|=|f(x)+f(-a)|=|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$. That's all.


$f(0) = 0$. Pf: $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)$. So $f(0)=0$.
$f(-x)=-f(x)$.  Pf:  $f(x)+f(-x)=f(x+(-x))=f(0)=0$ so $f(-x)=-f(x)$.
$|x-a|=|(x-a)-0|$
$|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(x)+f(-a)|=|f(x-a)|=|f(x-a)-0|=|f(x-a)-f(0)|$

From those four facts the result follows directly from the definition of continuity.

This is a duplicate, for example,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062760/fxy-fxfy-continuous-at-x-0-0-implies-fx-is-continuous-over-r

You may replace with $x-a$ by keeping in mind $x$ is just variable that can be any value within constraints.
If we make a dependent variable $x' = x-a$ then $|x'|<\delta \iff |x-a| < \delta$ and (once we prove $f(0)=0$ and $f(-a)=-f(a)$[1]) we also have $|f(x')-f(0)|<\epsilon \iff |f(x-a)-0|=|f(x)+f(-a)|=|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$ and our result follows immediately.
(Just restate the definition for continuity at $x'=0$ and we get the definition of continuity at $x = a$.)
Of course one doesn't have to explicitly create an $x'=x-a$.  One can legitimately just state "for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so whenever $|(x-a) - 0| < \delta$ then $|f(x-a)-f(0)| < \epsilon$. This means for all $x$ so that $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x-a)-f(0)|=|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$".  But if one asks if replacing $x$ with $x-a$ is legitimate... this is why.
(I also find replace the words "For all $x$ so that $|x-a| < \delta$" with "Whenever $|x-a|< \delta$" assures that we aren't actually number jiggling for completely different numbers.)
========
[1]  $f(0) = f(0+0)= f(0) + f(0)$ so $0 = f(0)$ and $f(a) + f(-a)= f(a+(-a)) = 0$ so $f(-a) = -f(a)$.

I'm having a tough time following your proof [original version at least] I am sorry. Rereading it again it appears you have the right idea but a couple steps could be explained more explicitly
I would do this as follows:
$f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$ and $f(0)=0$ as you already noted:
$\implies$ For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ s.t. $|f(\delta')|, |f(-\delta')| \le \epsilon$ for all nonnegative $\delta' \le \delta$. Here I'm using the definition of continuity.
$\implies$ For all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ s.t. the inequality $|f(a) +f(\delta') -f(a)|$ $\le$ $|f(a) + \epsilon-f(a)| = \epsilon$
and likewise, the inequality $|f(a) + f(-\delta) -f(a)|$ $\le$ $\epsilon$ holds, for all nonnegative
$\delta' \le \delta$. This is just simple algebra applied to the previous step; e.g., $f(\delta')$ $=$ $f(a)+f(\delta')-f(a)$.
$\implies$ For all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ s.t. the relations  $|f(a+\delta') - f(a)|$ $=$ $|f(a) +f(\delta') - f(a)|$ $\le \epsilon$, and the relations
$|f(a-\delta')-f(a)|$ $=$ $|f(a) + f(-\delta)-f(a)|$ $\le  \epsilon$ hold, for all nonnegative
$\delta' \le \delta$. Here I use the previous statement and apply the property that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all reals $x,y$.
$\implies$ For all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x)$ is indeed continuous at $x=a$, by definition of continuity.

If $f$ is continuous at $x=0$
Then Choose $\epsilon>0$ and we will have $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$
Now let $a\in \mathbb R$
For any choice of $\epsilon>0$
$$ |f(x) -f(a) |=|f(x-a) |<\epsilon$$
Whenever $|x-a|<\delta$
Hence f is continuous over all $\mathbb R$

Nitpick.  How do you know that $f(x-a)= f(x) + f(-a)= f(x)- f(a)$?  We don't know that $f(-a) = -f(a)$.... yet.

@fleablood Since $f(0)=0$ the result $f(-a)=-f(a)$ is rather trivial, as it directly follows from $f(a-a)=f(a)+f(-a)=0\Longrightarrow f(-a)=-f(a)$
